# Overload int() in Python

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading

Say I have a basic class in Python 3 which represents some number-like data-type. I want to make it so when I have an instance, x, of this class I can call int(x) and have it call my conversion function to return the integer portion.

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't seem to find out how to do it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You override the `__int__` magic method as per the following example...

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __int__(self):
        return self.i * 2

t = Test(5)
print( int(t) )
# 10
```

Answer (score 8):

Override the [`__int__()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__) method.

Comment: @Joel: [Not in the least.](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__complex__)

Comment: You learn something new everyday! Although I'm surprised I overlooked this while reading the docs :P