# how to make a class return integer instance

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, instance

I want my class to return an Integer instance like when you override `__str__` But Integer type. I don't understand why the following code wont work.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        global x
        x=5
    def __new__(cls):
        return  x       
print(A())
#it says: NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: this code is working for me..prints <__main__.A instance at 0x01E4A800>

Comment: I am using python 3.3 and i just checked it again. won't work.

Comment: @ConfuzzeledDavid It's because `__new__` is called before `__init__`. Plus whatever you are trying to do is pure evil. What's the point in overriding `__new__` like you do? Just use a function.

Comment: You mention `__str__` so are you after the same for [`__int__`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575393/overload-int-in-python)? Or - are you trying to subclass/otherwise implement your own `int` like object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> class A:
    def __new__(cls):
        return 5
>>> A()
5
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what i wanted.