# How to make type cast for python custom class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, casting

Consider a class;

```
class temp:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

I make an object of it;

```
obj = temp()
```

Convert it to string;

```
strObj = str(obj)
```

Now, how can i convert strObj to an object of temp class??

```
org = temp(strObj)
```

Comment: I do not think you can do something like that, why do you need this?

Comment: You need a constructor that can create the object from a string. `def __init__(self, x=""):`, if you want to use more than one constructor look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python

Comment: This is an experiment. I want to insert a class instance to MongoDB. But can't do it directly, so i had to convert it to a string.. Now, i need to convert it back.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong conversion, what you want is `object serialization` , do not use `str(..)` for that.

Comment: @markiz the link was really good!.. understood the approach of multiple constructors.. But can you explain how to convert a string to object?

Comment: If you want to recreate the object from the string, you should be using its `repr` not `str` form. If you want to put it in a database, why not have a table where each row is an instance and each field is an instance attribute?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65543940/how-can-i-type-cast-a-non-primitive-custom-class-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by Anand in comments, what you're looking for is object serialization and deserialization. One way to achieve this is through the pickle (or cPickle) module:

```
>>> import pickle

>>> class Example():
...     def __init__(self, x):
...             self.x = x
...
>>> a = Example('foo')
>>> astr = pickle.dumps(a) # (i__main__\nExample\np0\n(dp1\nS'x'\np2\nS'foo'\np3\nsb.
>>> b = pickle.loads(astr)
>>> b
<__main__.Example instance at 0x101c89ea8>
>>> b.x
'foo'
```

Note, however, that one gotcha in using the pickle module is dealing with implementation versions. As suggested in the Python docs, if you want an unpickled instance to automatically handle implementation versioning, you may want to add a version instance attribute and add a custom __setstate__ implementation: [https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.**setstate**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__). Otherwise, the version of the object at serialization time will be exactly what you get at deserialization time, regardless of code changes made to the object itself.

Comment: Thank you for simplifying things!

Answer (score 16):

For those who are looking for overriding conversion builtins such as `int(obj)`, `float(obj)`, and `str(obj)`, see [Overload int() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575393/overload-int-in-python). You need to implement `__int__`, `__float__`, or `__str__` on the object.

Answer (score 8):

To answer the question, one way of doing this is by "abusing" [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) in combination with [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). Let's first have a look at the `__repr__` docs (emphasis: mine):

> Called by the repr() built-in function to compute the “official”
>   string representation of an object. **If at all possible, this should
>   look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an
>   object with the same value (given an appropriate environment).** If this
>   is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...>
>   should be returned. The return value must be a string object. If a
>   class defines `__repr__()` but not `__str__()`, then `__repr__()` is also
>   used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that
>   class is required.
>
> This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the
>   representation is information-rich and unambiguous.

With this in mind, we know that it is recommended to return a string from `__repr__` which can be used with `eval()`. This is implied by the statement that the value "should look like a valid Python expression".

### Example

Here is an example which uses this. The example also overrides `__eq__`, but only for convenience for the print-outs. And for completeness we also add a value to the instance.

The example creates a new instance. Then the value is converted to a string using `__repr__` (by using the [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) function. Next that string value is passed to [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) which will evaluate the string and return the result. The result will be a new instance of the same class and is stored in `second_instance`. We also print out the [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) to visualise that we have indeed two different instances. Finally we show that `first_instance == second_instance` is indeed `True`:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(self, MyClass) and self.value == other.value

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.value)


first_instance = MyClass(123)
print('First instance: repr=%r, id=%d' % (first_instance, id(first_instance)))

stringified = repr(first_instance)
print('Stringified: %r' % stringified)

second_instance = eval(stringified)  # !!! DANGEROUS (see below) !!!
print('Second instance: repr=%r, id=%d' % (second_instance, id(second_instance)))

print('First == Second: %r' % (first_instance == second_instance))
```

### When is it OK to do this?

This is *100%* acceptable if **absolutely everything going into `eval()`** is under your control! This means:

- The scope in which `eval()` is called is under your control
- *No place* in the evaluated string should contain data coming from outside sources. Outside sources include:

  - Database values
  - User-Input
  - Data read from disk
  - ... basically any I/O

Keeping all this in mind and guaranteeing that at no point in the future of the project I/O will end up in an `eval()` call is almost impossible. As such I strongly recommend avoiding this in important production code as it opens up nasty security holes.

For code not running in production, this is absolutely acceptable. For example unit-tests, personal utility scripts, e.t.c. But the risk should always be taken into consideration.

### Why is this Dangerous?

- The code passed into `eval()` is executed inside the Python process calling it, with the same privileges. Example: You read a value from a DB where multiple users have access and you `eval()` it. In that case, another user may inject code via the database and that code will run *as your user*!
- Using `eval()` when the values come from outside sources opens up the possibility of code-injections.
- It is not guaranteed that `repr()` will return a valid Python expression. This is only a *recommendation* by the docs. Hence the call to `eval` with `__repr__` is prone to run-time errors.
- In the example above, the scope calling `eval()` needs to "know" about the class `MyClass` (it must be imported). It only looks for the name. So if by pure chance that same name exists in the scope, but pointing to another object, you will call something else unintentionally and may run into weird bugs. Granted, this is an edge-case.

### Safer Alternative

Use one of the many available serialisation options. The most popular, and simplest one to use is to convert the object to/from JSON strings. The above example could be made safe like this:

```
import json


class MyClass:

    @staticmethod
    def from_json(document):
        data = json.loads(document)
        instance = MyClass(data['value'])
        return instance

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(self, MyClass) and self.value == other.value

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.value)

    def to_json(self):
        data = {
            'value': self.value
        }
        return json.dumps(data)


first_instance = MyClass(123)
print('First instance: repr=%r, id=%d' % (first_instance, id(first_instance)))

stringified = first_instance.to_json()
print('Stringified: %r' % stringified)

second_instance = MyClass.from_json(stringified)
print('Second instance: repr=%r, id=%d' % (second_instance, id(second_instance)))

print('First == Second: %r' % (first_instance == second_instance))
```

This is only marginally more difficult but much safer.

The same approach can be used with other serialisation methods. Popular formats are:

- [XML](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)
- [YAML](https://pyyaml.org)
- [ini/cfg files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)
- [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) (note that this uses bytes instead of text as serialisation medium).
- [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/) (note that this uses bytes instead of text as serialisation medium).
- Custom Implementation
- ...

Answer (score 0):

What if you define a class constructor depending on the type of argument being passed. Moreover, if you want to allow the creation of an object without the arguments passed, the arguments can be put in *args. In the code below constructor checks the number and type of argument(s) and depending on it write to the `self.attr` different values.
Something like that:

```
class temp():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) > 0:
            if isinstance(args[0],str):
                self.attr = args[0]
            else:
                self.attr = 'Not a string'
        else:
            self.attr = 'Not a string'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.attr

obj = temp()
obj.attr = 'Hello World'
strObj = str(obj)
org = temp(strObj)
```

Comment: Could you please give a brief explanation of the solution and why it solves the problem in the question?

Comment: I've tried to enhance post by explanation of an idea. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dedicated class for handling casting leveraging the json library and built in methods.

Sample Cast class:

```
import json

class Cast(object):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Cast, self).__init__()

  @staticmethod
  def _to(clazz, obj):
    if (clazz == str):
      return json.dumps(obj, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__)
    else:
      newinstance = clazz()
      if (isinstance(obj, str)):
        jsonObj = json.loads(obj)
        sharedKeys = jsonObj.keys()
        for objKey in sharedKeys:
          setattr(newinstance, objKey, jsonObj[objKey])
      else:
        # Test/Convert for other standard or custom types
        pass
      return newinstance
```

### Code Explanation:

- The Cast._to method, is used to cast your custom object, to the desired class. Use the flow control to handle various cases.
- In this example, if casting to a str class, it will use the json dumps to convert the object to a json string.
- When casting to anything other than string, use the built in isinstance method to handle how a specified object will be converted via flow control.
- In this example, for the first else block, it is assumed that the object is a json string.
- The json loads method then converts it into a dict representing the clazz object. The keys are extracted, which will be the same keys as any instance of the clazz object.
  The keys are used to extract the values from the json object and pass them to a new class instance using the built in setattr.
- ***Key thing to note about the Cast._to**. For the first else block to work, the custom "clazz" to cast to, **must** have **either** a no args constructor **or** default values for all arguments.
  This is a similar approach to Java, which always has a default no args constructor, except in this in case you can use a constructor with args as long as the args have default values.*

### Test

```
class temp(object):

  def __init__(self, attr1=None, attr2=None, attr3=None):
    super(temp, self).__init__()
    self.attr1 = attr1
    self.attr2 = attr2
    self.attr3 = attr3
    self.attr4 = None

def __main__():
  obj = temp()
  strObj = Cast._to(str, obj)
  org = Cast._from(strObj, temp)
  print(type(org))
  print(org.attr2)

  obj2 = temp("OdinsBeard", "Gungnir")
  obj2.attr4 = "Fenrir"
  strObj2 = Cast._to(str, obj2)
  org2 = Cast._from(strObj2, temp)
  print(type(org2))
  print(org2.attr2)


__main__()
```

### Output:

<class '**main**.temp'>
None
<class '**main**.temp'>
Gungnir

### Additional options:

If you want your custom object to automatically be eligible as a json string when calling str() and when printing from an array, then you would need to override the custom class's __str__ and __repr__ methods respectively.

```
  def __str__(self):
    return json.dumps(self, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__)

  def __repr__(self):
    return json.dumps(self, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__)
```

### Test

Using the same setup as the first test above but with the newly added __str__ and __repr__ methods, the outputs is as below.

```
  print(str(obj))
  print(str(obj2))

#Output Below:
{"attr4": null, "attr2": null, "attr3": null, "attr1": null}
{"attr4": "Fenrir", "attr2": "Gungnir", "attr3": null, "attr1": "OdinsBeard"}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is a constructor to your class. Simply define a constructor that checks if the argument passed is a string. Then do any more changes that you might want to do to create the object from the string.

```
class obj():
   def __init__(self, attribs*):
       if len(attribs)==1 and type(attribs[0])=='str':
           #your string manipulations go here
           self.content = attribs[0].upper()
```