# How can I type cast a non-primitive, custom class in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

### How can I cast a `var` into a `CustomClass`?

In Python, I can use `float(var)`, `int(var)` and `str(var)` to cast a variable into primitive data types but I can't use `CustomClass(var)` to cast a variable into a `CustomClass` unless I have a constructor for that variable type.

**Example with inheritance.**

```
class CustomBase:
    pass

class CustomClass(CustomBase):
    def foo():
        pass

def bar(var: CustomBase):
    if isinstance(var, CustomClass):
        # customClass = CustomClass(var)   <-- Would like to cast here...
        # customClass.foo()                <-- to make it clear that I can call foo here.
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? ``if isinstance(var, CustomClass)`` already guarantees that ``var`` "is a" ``CustomClass`` in the branch. There is no need to "cast" ``var`` to a ``CustomClass``, since it already is one. Be aware that ``float(var)`` etc. work precisely because ``float`` etc. have a constructor specifically made to deal with various types (namely those implementing ``__float__`` etc.).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I realised what I was after was actually the static type casting to be correct for variables that I now know are a certain type so that I can use my IDE's tools for working with those variables (eg. autocomplete and static type checking). The original question doesn't reflect this and I do need to update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the process of writing this question I believe I've found a solution.

### Python is using [Duck-typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing)

Therefore it is not necessary to cast before calling a function.

Ie. the following is functionally fine.

```
def bar(var):
    if isinstance(var, CustomClass):
        customClass.foo()
```

### I actually wanted static type casting on variables

I want this so that I can continue to get all the lovely benefits of the `typing` [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) in my IDE such as checking function input types, warnings for non-existant class methods, autocompleting methods, etc.

For this I believe *re-typing* (not sure if this is the correct term) is a suitable solution:

```
class CustomBase:
    pass

class CustomClass(CustomBase):
    def foo():
        pass

def bar(var: CustomBase):
    if isinstance(var, CustomClass):
        customClass: CustomClass = var
        customClass.foo()  # Now my IDE doesn't report this method call as a warning.
```