# How to add properties to standard types?

Tags: python

I want to add custom properties to the standard Python types (e.g. a `size` property to the `str` type), but the code below doesn't seem to do the trick; I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'size'`. What's wrong?

```
import __builtin__

class str2(str):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(str2, self).__init__(text)
        self.size = len(self)

__builtin__.str = str2

print str2("foo").size # This works
print str("bar").size # This also works
print "baz".size # But this doesn't
```

Comment: First, I doubt you have a good use case to monkey-patch string. Second, i doubt there is an easy way since it's C-implemented (for CPython of course)

Comment: But assuming I had a good reason to monkey-patch string, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you give us the good reason? (I think there is likely a better way to solve your actual issue)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204937/is-there-any-way-to-override-pythons-built-in-class