# Python type-hint friendly type that constrains possible values

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading, python-typing, constructor-overloading

I want a python type-hint friendly way to create a Type that has constrained range of values.

For example, a *URL* Type based on type `str` that would only accept strings that look like an "http" URL.

```
# this code is made up and will not compile
class URL(typing.NewType('_URL', str)):
    def __init__(self, value: str, *args, **kwargs):
        if not (value.startswith('http://') or value.startswith('https://')):
            raise ValueError('string is not an acceptable URL')
```

Answer (score 14):

### overriding built-in immutable types works well

#### overriding `str`; http URL strings

Here is an example overriding `str`.  This does not require the `typing` module but still works with type-hinting.

This `str` derived class asserts the initialized string looks like an http URL string.

```python
class URL(str):
    def __new__(cls, *value):
        if value:
            v0 = value[0]
            if not type(v0) is str:
                raise TypeError('Unexpected type for URL: "%s"' % type(v0))
            if not (v0.startswith('http://') or v0.startswith('https://')):
                raise ValueError('Passed string value "%s" is not an'
                                 ' "http*://" URL' % (v0,))
        # else allow None to be passed. This allows an "empty" URL instance, e.g. `URL()`
        # `URL()` evaluates False

        return str.__new__(cls, *value)
```

This results in a class that will only allow some strings.  Otherwise, it behaves like an immutable `str` instance.

```python
# these are okay
URL()
URL('http://example.com')
URL('https://example.com')
URL('https://')

# these raise ValueError
URL('example')  # ValueError: Passed string value "example" is not an "http*://" URL
URL('')  # ValueError: Passed string value "" is not an "http*://" URL

# these evaluate as you would expect
for url in (URL(),  # 'False'
            URL('https://'),  # 'True'
            URL('https://example.com'),  # 'True'
           ):
    print('True') if url else print('False')
```

(update: later on I found the [purl](https://github.com/codeinthehole/purl) Python library)

Another example,

#### overriding `int`; constrained integer range `Number`

This `int` derived class only allows values `1` through `9` inclusive.

This has a special feature, too.  In case an instance is initialized with nothing (`Number()`) then that value equates to `0` (this behavior is derived from the `int` class). In that case, the `__str__` should be a `'.'` (program requirement).

```python
class Number(int):
    """integer type with constraints; part of a Sudoku game"""

    MIN = 1  # minimum
    MAX = 9  # maximum

    def __new__(cls, *value):
        if value:
            v0 = int(value[0])
            if not (cls.MIN <= v0 <= cls.MAX):
                raise ValueError('Bad value "%s" is not acceptable in'
                                 ' Sudoku' % (v0,))
        # else:
        #    allow None to be passed. This allows an "empty" Number instance that
        #    evaluates False, e.g. `Number()`

        return int.__new__(cls, *value)

    def __str__(self):
        """print the Number accounting for an "empty" value"""
        if self == 0:
            return '.'
        return int.__str__(self)
```

This ensures errant inputs are handled sooner rather than later.  Otherwise, it behaves just like an `int`.

```python
# these are okay
Number(1)
Number(9)
Number('9')

# this will evaluate True, just like an int
Number(9) == int(9)
Number('9') == int(9)
Number('9') == float(9)

# this is okay, it will evaluate False
Number()
print('True') if Number() else print('False')  # 'False'

# these raise ValueError
Number(0)  # ValueError: Bad value "0" is not acceptable in Sudoku
Number(11)  # ValueError: Bad value "11" is not acceptable in Sudoku
Number('11')  # ValueError: Bad value "11" is not acceptable in Sudoku
```

And the special "feature"

```python
print(Number(1)) # '1' (expected)
print(Number())  # '.' (special feature)
```

#### overriding `int`; class `RomanNumeral`

This same technique can be used to create a "Roman Numeral" class that accepts values from 0 to 10 written as [Roman Numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals). By overloading `__new__` the passed `value` can be correlated to a literal number value passed to the underlying `int.__new__` and `int.__init__`.

```python
from typing_extensions import Self


class RomanNumeral(int):
    """integer type that takes Roman Numerals strings from one to ten"""

    _value_s: str
    """value stored as Roman Numeral uppercase"""

    def __new__(cls, *value) -> Self:
        if value is None or not len(value):
            raise ValueError("RomanNumeral requires a string value, given None")
        val = value[0]
        if not isinstance(val, str):
            raise TypeError("value must be type str, given %s" % type(val))
        val_u = val.upper()
        if val_u == "I":
            rn = super().__new__(cls, 1)
        elif val_u == "II":
            rn = super().__new__(cls, 2)
        elif val_u == "III":
            rn = super().__new__(cls, 3)
        elif val_u == "IV":
            rn = super().__new__(cls, 4)
        elif val_u == "V":
            rn = super().__new__(cls, 5)
        elif val_u == "VI":
            rn = super().__new__(cls, 6)
        elif val_u == "VII":
            rn = super().__new__(cls, 7)
        elif val_u == "VIII":
            rn = super().__new__(cls, 8)
        elif val_u == "IX":
            rn = super().__new__(cls, 9)
        elif val_u == "X":
            rn = super().__new__(cls, 10)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown Roman Numeral value %r" % val_u)
        rn._value_s = val_u
        return rn

    def __str__(self):
        return self._value_s
```

---

Technique for [inheriting immutable types is derived from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2673863/471376).

Comment: Assertions can be turned off. `assert` shouldn't be used for control flow.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 fixed.  Uses `TypeError` instead.  Thanks.

Comment: are these runtime errors or compile time type checking errors?

Comment: "_are these runtime errors or compile time type checking errors?_" the `ValueError` occur at runtime.

Comment: Note another approach is to add method `__int__` or `__float__` to a class.  See [_Overload int() in Python_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575393/overload-int-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

Subclassing builtin types can lead to some odd cases (consider code which checks exactly `type(...) is str`)

Here is a pure-typing approach which is typesafe and fully preserves the type of your strings:

```
from typing import NewType

_Url = NewType('_Url', str)

def URL(s: str) -> _Url:
    if not s.startswith('https://'):
        raise AssertionError(s)
    return _Url(s)

print(type(URL('https://example.com')) is str)  # prints `True`
```

The approach here "hides" the runtime checking behind a function which looks like a constructor from an api perspective, but in reality is just a [tiny type](https://darrenhobbs.com/2007/04/11/tiny-types/) (I couldn't find a canonical reference to "tiny types" this appears to just be the best resource I could find).