# Python: overwrite __int__

Tags: python, numpy

A working solution, which returns integers, was given in [Overload int() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575393).

However, it works only for returning `int`, but not `float` or let's say a list:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, mylist):
        self.mylist = mylist
    def __int__(self):
        return list(map(int, self.mylist))

t = Test([1.5, 6.1])
t.__int__()   # [1, 6]
int(t)
```

Thus `t.__int__()` works, but `int(t)` gives `TypeError: __int__ returned non-int (type list)`.

Thus, is there a possibility to fully overwrite `int`, maybe with `__getattribute__` or `metaclass`?

Comment: The method `__int__` is a toInt so it should return an int not a list

Comment: The idea of `int`, `str`, etc. is that they call the underlying `__int__`, `__str__`, and perform this typecheck. By contract `str(..)` should return an instance of a `string`.

Comment: ``__int__`` does not overwrite ``int``. The method is a hook used by ``int`` when it does not understand its argument type.

Comment: This does not make any sense. **The point** of `__int__` is to explain how to convert an instance of the class **to an integer**. You get this `TypeError` because you are trying to use the function for a fundamentally wrong and confused purpose. There is **no reason to expect** that returning something other than an integer from `__int__` would work, and **no sensible way to say** what it should mean if you could.

Comment: `int`, meanwhile, **is the class itself** that integers belong to - **not** a function. It gets to decide what is returned when you call the class, and like most normal classes, it only returns instances of the class. (Unlike most classes, it can return instances that already existed.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The accepted answer shows that this question is not a duplicate, but seeks for a superior solution. My comment there also gives a use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__int__`, `__float__`, ... special methods and various others do not overwrite their respective type such as `int`, `float`, etc. These methods serve as hooks that allow *the types* to ask for an appropriate value. The types will still enforce that a proper type is provided.

If required, one can actually overwrite `int` and similar on the `builtins` module. This can be done anywhere, and has global effect.

```
import builtins

# store the original ``int`` type as a default argument
def weakint(x, base=None, _real_int=builtins.int):
    """A weakly typed ``int`` whose return type may be another type"""
    if base is None:
        try:
            return type(x).__int__(x)
        except AttributeError:
            return _real_int(x)
    return _real_int(x, base)

# overwrite the original ``int`` type with the weaker one
builtins.int = weakint
```

Note that replacing builtin types may violate assumptions of code about these types, e.g. that `type(int(x)) is int` holds true. Only do so if absolutely required.

This is an example of how to replace `int(...)`. It will break various features of `int` being a type, e.g. checking inheritance, unless the replacement is a carefully crafted type. A full replacement requires emulating the initial `int` type, e.g. via [custom subclassing checks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks), and will not be completely possible for some builtin operations.

Comment: Thanks! A smart hack.

Comment: Now, I can also smuggle numpy arrays through some pure python functions. Thus a dirty way to vectorise `int` is `import numpy as np; import builtins; builtins.int = lambda x: x.astype(np.int); int(np.array([1.5, 6.1]))`.

Answer (score 1):

From the doc of [`__int__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__)

> Called to implement the built-in functions complex(), int() and float(). Should return a value of the appropriate type.

Here your method return a `list` and not an `int`, this works when calling it explictly but not using `int()` which checks the type of what is returned by the `__int__`

---

Here is a working example of what if could be, even if the usage if not very pertinent

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, mylist):
        self.mylist = mylist
    def __int__(self):
        return int(sum(self.mylist))
```